# cannot run ng serve - page keep loading

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am confronting with the following issue, I do not really know what can cause this.

Please check the following attachment

[image]

When I try to run the server using `ng serve --open` the server starts and compiles everything. Immediately after the page opens I receive a blank window which seems to be waiting for something. By opening the devtools I noticed that the browser holds onto the selected file for a very long time (more than 1 min as you can see in the pic). If I click the button from the browser that is killing the current script, it says that the selected file was successfully returned with 200 code and immediately after that the websocker appears with 101 status. I do not know onto which one is hanging and why but it seems he is trying to switch some protocols.

If I manage to open the console of the browser fast enough, it prints messages like this `platform-browser.js:1770 Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.` without stopping.

Maybe this will be helpful

```
platform-browser.js:1770 Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js.BrowserPlatformLocation.replaceState @ platform-browser.js:1770
push../node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/common.js.PathLocationStrategy.replaceState @ common.js:731
push../node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/common.js.Location.replaceState @ common.js:307
push../node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js.Router.resetUrlToCurrentUrlTree @ router.js:5625
(anonymous) @ router.js:5574
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4760
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4751
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:23
(anonymous) @ dashboard-dashboard-module.js:1
platform-browser.js:1770 Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js.BrowserPlatformLocation.replaceState @ platform-browser.js:1770
push../node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/common.js.PathLocationStrategy.replaceState @ common.js:731
push../node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/common.js.Location.replaceState @ common.js:307
push../node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js.Router.resetUrlToCurrentUrlTree @ router.js:5625
(anonymous) @ router.js:5574
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4760
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4751
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:23
(anonymous) @ dashboard-dashboard-module.js:1
platform-browser.js:1770 Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.
```

...

The port is not occupied.

I am using

- angular cli 6.0.8
- windows 7 x64
- node 8.11.2

Any ideas why is this hanging?

Comment: have you read the console for any errors?

Comment: @Lewis there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @baao maybe someone had a similar issue. the code worked before updating some deps, angular-cli beeing one of them. I updated angular-cli from `"@angular/cli": "1.7.0"` to `"@angular/cli": "^6.0.8"`. I don't have any errors, stacktraces or any other useful outputs. I do not know where to begin with. I already spent a few hours on this.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @baao Angular 5. I added some more detailed logs from the browser console. It looks like he keeps trying to load a module.

Comment: Please try running ng update. Does this yield errors?